# Python Tkinter first script - window not showing

Tags: python, tkinter

I am really really new to Python, and have not done any serious coding for many years, so please bear with me.

I used the following script just to learn about Tkinter GUI codes.

```
import tkinter as tk
MYwindow=tk.Tk()
input("wait")
```

When using the IDLE line interpreter of Python, line 1 and line 2 would show the window frame created.

But when saving the code in a .py file, running the file, would not show the window anywhere at all.  So I added line #3, to stop the CMD window from closing, but the MYwindow is still not showing.

Have I missed some other initialisation code, environment setup, or something else?  Please help

Comment: The `mainloop` maybe?

Comment: I added while True: to the beginning, and get rid of the Input() line.  Same thing, no window drawn.

while True:
    import tkinter as tk
    MYwindow=tk.Tk()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re required to call the Tk’s `mainloop` when running the tkinter program as a script. It keeps the program alive and constantly receiving event. P.S. in most cases, you should never have a `while True` loop or anything that will interrupt the `mainloop`.

```
import tkinter as tk
MYwindow=tk.Tk()
Mywindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks.  Learning the ropes :-)